# Why do I get "syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator" in a line with a valid syntax

Tags: bash, binary, decimal

This is the snippet of my code

```
valueSum="$(($firstValueBinarytoDecimal+$secondValueBinarytoDecimal))"
                        decimalToBinary="$(("obase=2;$valueSum" | bc))" #error here
                        echo "$decimalToBinary"
```

On the marked code: `decimalToBinary="$(("obase=2;$valueSum" | bc))"`, I get an error message: `syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ";150 | bc")`

I've already run the exact same code separately and it's working

```
echo "obase=2;150" | bc
```

I thought maybe it could be that the `150` was acting as a string and not as an intager but then why I'm able to make the addition `$(($firstValueBinarytoDecimal+$secondValueBinarytoDecimal))`?

Somebody knows how can I fix this error?

Comment: `$(( expression ))` is an arithmetic expansion. You're probably looking for `$( command )` which is a command substitution. The error message is because bash can't figure out how to interpret `obase=2;150 | bc` as an arithmetic expression, but you really just need to execute it as a command.

Comment: I think you don't understand the role of `echo` in `echo "obase=2;150" | bc`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the corrected form of your line:

decimalToBinary="$( echo "obase=2;$valueSum" | bc )"